# $a(a + 2)$ is $a^2 + 2a$, but why? Should not we start with Parentheses?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The result of $a(a + 2)$ is $a^2  + 2a$, but why? Shouldn't we start with parentheses first?

Comment: Distributive property $$a\cdot(x+y)=ax+ay$$

Answer (score 2):

If you are computing, say, $7\times(7+2)$, yes, you compute first $7+2(=9)$, and then you compute $7\times 9(=63)$. However, by the distributive property, $7\times(7+2)$ is also equal to $7\times7+7\times2=7^2+7\times2$. And, by the same reason, $a(a+2)=a^2+a\times2=a^2+2a$.

Comment: Also, $a + 2$ is in simplest form, so the step to start with the parenthesis first can be skipped.

Comment: Thank you very much José! Now I learned something new :) 
However I should have asked the question in another way. The question was that I need to measure the the height of a triangle using algebra. The result of my answer was different from the one in the book. They wrote: 

x.(2x+8) / 2 = x.2(x + 4) / 2 and I didn't understand how did we get to x.2(x + 4) / 2 Any step by step clarification?

Thnx in advance!

Comment: It's because $x.(2x+8)=x.\bigl(2.(x+4)\bigr)=(x.2).(x+4)$.

Comment: Ok... But why change from .(2+8) to .(2.(+4))? What is the purpose of using .(2.(+4)) instead of .(2+8). What is the name of this method and why/where do we use it?

Comment: So that we can divide by $2$: $x.2(x+4)/2=x(x+4)$.